# Appending to External Browser Window

Tags: javascript

I have a Windows app that contains a browser control that loads pages from my website.  However, due to the Windows app, I cannot debug Javascript in the usual ways (Firebug, console, alerts, etc).

I was hoping to write a jQuery plug-in to log to an external browser window such that I can simply do something like:

```
$.log('test');
```

So far, with the following, I am able to create the window and display the templateContent, but cannot write messages to it:

```
var consoleWindow;

function getConsoleWindow() {
    if (typeof (consoleWindow) === 'undefined') {
        consoleWindow = createConsoleWindow();
    }

    return consoleWindow;
}

function createConsoleWindow() {
    var newConsoleWindow = window.open('consoleLog', '', 'status,height=200,width=300');
    var templateContent = '<html><head><title>Console</title></head>' +
                          '<body><h1>Console</h1><div id="console">' +
                          '<span id="consoleText"></span></div></body></html>';
    newConsoleWindow.document.write(templateContent);
    newConsoleWindow.document.close();
    return newConsoleWindow;
}

function writeToConsole(message) {
    var console = getConsoleWindow();
    var consoleDoc = console.document.open();
    var consoleMessage = document.createElement('span');
    consoleMessage.innerHTML = message;
    consoleDoc.getElementById('consoleText').appendChild(consoleMessage);
    consoleDoc.close();
}

jQuery.log = function (message) {
    if (window.console) {
        console.log(message);
    } else {
        writeToConsole(message);
    }
};
```

Currently, getElementById('consoleText') is failing.  Is what I'm after possible, and if so, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I don't close() the document, it appears to work as I hoped.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
consoleDoc.getElementById('consoleText');
```

right before

```
consoleDoc.getElementById('consoleText').appendChild(consoleMessage);
```

If the line you added is the one that fails, then that means consoleDoc is not right, if the next line is the only one that fails then ..ById('consoleText') is not matching up